# Сортировка массива структуры по 3м значения массива

Tags: c++, qsort

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

#define N 2

struct Znak {
    string fam, name, znak;
    int date[3] = { 0 };
};

void printOutput(Znak ad) {
    cout << "Фамилия: " << ad.fam << endl;
    cout << "Имя: " << ad.name << endl;
    cout << "Знак зодиака: " << ad.znak << endl;
    cout << "Дата рождения: " << ad.date[0] << "." << ad.date[1] << "." << ad.date[2] << endl;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    Znak user[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << "Введите следующие данные: Фамилию, Имя, Знак Зодиака, Дату рождения:\n";
        cin >> user[i].fam >> user[i].name >> user[i].znak >> user[i].date[0] >> user[i].date[1] >> user[i].date[2];
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printOutput(*user);
    };

    qsort(user, N, sizeof);



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Подскажите как можно реализовать сортировку массива user по полю дата рождения(массив из 3х элементов)?

Не могу понять как реализовать тут через qsort.

для qsort(user,N, ?,?)

(?)- не знаю какие параметры указать и как их написать

Comment: надо сначала язык изучать, потом qsort

Answer (score 0):

Так как вы хотите отсортировать массив структур вам необходимо определить операцию сравнения двух структур. Так как вы хотите отсортировать лишь по одному полю структуры, то операцию сравнения лучше не определять в структуре как `operator<`, а реализовать отдельно, вроде:

```cpp
auto comparator = [](const Struct &first, const Struct &second) {
  if (first.val < second.val) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

Однако, так как поле, по котором вы хотите сравнивать, это массив объектов то так сделать не получится. Придется сравнивать сначала первую пару чисел, потом вторую и наконец третью. Можно воспользоваться небольшой хитростью: оператор `less` для `tuple` сравнивает поочередно каждую пару значений, как раз как нам нужно

```cpp
...
if (std::make_tuple(first.val[0], first.val[1], fist.val[2]) < std::make_tuple(second.val[0], second.val[1], second.val[2])) {
...
```

Ну а дальше остается лишь вызвать алгоритм сортировки для нашего массива

```cpp
std::vector<Struct> arr;
...

std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), comparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

С qsort как-то так:

```
int compar(const void * a_, const void * b_) {
    const Znak * a = (const Znak *)a_;
    const Znak * b = (const Znak *)b_;

    if (a->date[2] > b->date[2]) return 1;
    if (a->date[2] < b->date[2]) return -1;
    if (a->date[1] > b->date[1]) return 1;
    if (a->date[1] < b->date[1]) return -1;
    if (a->date[0] > b->date[0]) return 1;
    if (a->date[0] < b->date[0]) return -1;
    return 0;
}

qsort(user, N, sizeof(Znak), compar);
```

В функции сравниваем сначала год, потом месяц, потом день.

Но в С++ проще использовать `sort`.